# Save products with php function in prestashop-1.7

Tags: php, function, prestashop-1.7

I have a problem with my website, made with prestashop-1.7, when displaying products. I have 7500 products in the database, but for some strange reason, only shows 4100 on the web. To show it, i have to go to the product section in the backoffice and save it, but with more than 3000 products it would take forever.

To solve this i'm thinking of calling the Save() function withing a php file that works with the products to save all of them.

I'm missing many concepts of php, so i ask for guidance on whether it would be possible to do it and in which file i could create the function.

Thank you and i await your response.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that your products are not properly indexed in frontend search (this is typical if they were imported directly in SQL or through a CSV-import tool).

If this is the case just go in your backoffice **Shop Parameters > Search** and click **Re-build the entire index** , this should solve the issue without the hassle of saving all products.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! Your solution should work, but i guess it will change the id of all old products, right?

Comment: No - This would only act on products frontend search indexation (it will fill the ps_search_* table and set product indexed = 1) without touching their ids or nothing at product database level.

Comment: Great!! Thank you for the explication.